# How do I find out if one Python function is an alias for another one?

Tags: python, file, alias, file-handling

In this question - [What's the difference between io.open() and os.open() on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219511/whats-the-difference-between-io-open-and-os-open-on-python) - I learned that Python `open()` function is an alias to the `io.open()` function.

My question is how do I find out if one Python function aliases another one?

I thought `id()` function will help me out but in the case of `open()` and `io.open()` it returns different values:

```py
>>> import io
>>> id(open)
140172515129392
>>> id(io.open)
28340168
```

I'm using Python 2.7.3

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: You're testing it in wrong Python version, try it in Python 3.

Comment: @NPE it's not always about solving a problem. In my case it's just learning. Going deeper helps me better understand it.

Comment: @golem: That makes sense, and comparing the ids or using the `is` operator is the way to go. Bear in mind that there are many way for this check to break down (for example, a simple wrapper -- such as a lambda function -- would have a different `id`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3, the `open()` function is indeed the same object:

```
>>> sys.version
'3.4.2 (default, Nov 29 2014, 18:28:46) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.54)]'
>>> id(open)
4467734600
>>> id(io.open)
4467734600
>>> io.open is open
True
```

This is **not** the case in Python 2 however. The `io` module is available for forward compatibility, but the old I/O subsystem is still the default:

```
>>> import sys, io
>>> sys.version
'2.7.8 (default, Nov 29 2014, 18:24:03) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.54)]'
>>> io.open is open
False
```

The `io` library was [added to Python 2.6](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3116-new-i-o-library):

> In Python 2.6, the underlying implementations haven’t been restructured to build on top of the `io` module’s classes. The module is being provided to make it easier to write code that’s forward-compatible with 3.0, and to save developers the effort of writing their own implementations of buffering and text I/O.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.4,

```
>>> import io
>>> open is io.open
True
```

In Python 2.x they are different objects, and you will get `False` instead.

Comment: Doesn't work in CPython 2.7.3 (and clearly not in the OP's case, where the two `id`s differ).

Comment: @NPE it does work - it's just that in 2.7 `open` doesn't use `io.open`

Comment: @JonClements: I think that needs to be spelled out in the answer.

Comment: @NPE looks like Martijn's already covered it in his answer :)

Comment: @JonClements: He did, and that's why his answer got my upvote. :-) That aside, I still can't shake off the feeling that there's a bit of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) going on in this question.

Comment: @NPE, thanks for pointing out that such a notion exists. After some speculation I think that I indeed posed my question such that it looks like an XY Problem. I should have probably divided the question in two: 1) What is the correct way of finding out if one function is an alias of another; and 2) Are open() and io.open() functions truly the same thing. Anyway I've got my answers.

Comment: @golem: As long as you got your answers, that's all that matters. It's just that we often see XY questions, and the whole thing turns into quite a frustrating experience for both the person asking and those trying to help. :-)