# Difference bewteen open from __builtin__.py and open from os module

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the difference when opening a file via the following two methods?
`open(name, mode=None, buffering=None)' from __builtin__.py` versus
`os.open` signature: open(filename, flag, mode=0777)

When should I use each of them?
I've also heard of the existence of `io.open`

Comment: There are huge differences. Look at the return type; the `os` call is a *low level* call, the `open()` built-in high-level. Stick to the latter unless you know what you are doing (e.g. know how to use a file descriptor (an integer) to access the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219511/whats-the-difference-between-io-open-and-os-open-on-python

Comment: The `io` module is the new Python 3 I/O framework, it replaced the older Python 2 implementation. It is available in Python 2 so you can write code that works on both Python 2 and 3, or you can use it because it is so much  better than the old way.