# How do you create in python a file with permissions other users can write

Tags: python, permissions

How can I in python (3) create a file what others users can write as well.
I've so far this but it changes the

```
os.chmod("/home/pi/test/relaxbank1.txt", 777)
with open("/home/pi/test/relaxbank1.txt", "w") as fh:
    fh.write(p1)
```

what I get

> ---sr-S--t  1 root root    12 Apr 20 13:21 relaxbank1.txt

expected (after doing in commandline $ sudo chmod 777 relaxbank1.txt
)

> -rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    12 Apr 20 13:21 relaxbank1.txt

Answer (score 109, accepted):

If you don't want to use `os.chmod` and prefer to have the file created with appropriate permissions, then you may use [`os.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.open) to create the appropriate file descriptor and then `open` the descriptor:

```py
import os

# The default umask is 0o22 which turns off write permission of group and others
os.umask(0)

descriptor = os.open(
    path='filepath',
    flags=(
        os.O_WRONLY  # access mode: write only
        | os.O_CREAT  # create if not exists
        | os.O_TRUNC  # truncate the file to zero
    ),
    mode=0o777
)

with open(descriptor, 'w') as fh:
    fh.write('some text')
    # the descriptor is automatically closed when fh is closed
```

Using a custom `opener` will make things easier and less error-prone. [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) will generate the appropriate `flags` for our `opener` according to the requested mode (`w`):

```py
import os

os.umask(0)


def opener(path, flags):
    return os.open(path, flags, 0o777)


with open('filepath', 'w', opener=opener) as fh:
    fh.write('some text')
```

**Python 2 Note:**

The built-in [open()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) in Python 2.x doesn't support opening by file descriptor. Use [`os.fdopen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fdopen) instead; otherwise you'll get:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found.
```

Comment: This is a better approach than the accepted answer. When you need to create a file with more restrictive permissions than the default umask, updating permissions after the file is created is a security bug.

Comment: ERROR: "TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found"

Comment: This is the better option, and I changed this to the accepted answer. Thank you for your effort to share this with us.

Comment: This assumes that the process is not multi-threaded. This is not any safer in a mtli-threaded application, since there is no guarantee that the umask will be active when the file access occurs.

Comment: There is one other "trap" in this code sample; one might assume `os.O_CREAT | os.O_WRONLY` are the flags that `open('filepath', 'w')` would normally set, but an important flag `O_TRUNC` is missing here. If you use this code to (sometimes) write a file that already exists, and the new content you are writing is shorter than the original content, then this code sample will leave garbage at the end of the file, in a way that I believe would be surprising to most non-experts, like me, and is inconsistent with the default python behavior.

Comment: @Tao: You are totally right. I've updated my answer. The new suggestion is to use `opener` when possible to avoid such issues.

Answer (score 30):

The problem is your call to `open()` recreates the call. Either you need to move the `chmod()` to after you close the file, OR change the file mode to `w+`.

Option1:

```
with open("/home/pi/test/relaxbank1.txt", "w+") as fh:
    fh.write(p1)
os.chmod("/home/pi/test/relaxbank1.txt", 0o777)
```

Option2:

```
os.chmod("/home/pi/test/relaxbank1.txt", 0o777)
with open("/home/pi/test/relaxbank1.txt", "w+") as fh:
    fh.write(p1)
```

Comment: Option1 is slightly better as it handles the condition where the file may not already exist (in which case the `os.chmod()` will throw an exception).

Comment: The suggested  "0777"  gives an error:      os.chmod("/home/pi/test richard/relaxbank1.txt",0777)    Error message: SyntaxError: invalid token    However "777" don't give an error but change the permission in -r----x--t  1 root root    12 Apr 20 15:37 relaxbank1.txt
 
                                                       ^

Comment: My bad -- correct octal notation is `0o777` (zero, letter 'o', 777)

Comment: what does the `0o` in the `0o777` do/mean?

Comment: ah, I see,  for those who are wondering about the leading  `0o` in the `0o777`  it is to make the number octal see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607903/python-module-os-chmodfile-664-does-not-change-the-permission-to-rw-rw-r-bu)

Comment: This answer may be **dangerous** for future readers.  It is only secure because the OP is asking to change the permissions to be **less restrictive**.  Future readers be-ware this is not secure if you want to make the permissions *more restrictive*.  That's because there is time between the file being created and the permissions being changed.  So a malicious agent may be able to open the file before the permissions change and keep it open.   See here for a secure solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45368120/453851

Answer (score 13):

Similar to AXO's idea where it's preferable to have the file created with the correct permissions, the `opener` argument of `open()` seems quite handy for this purpose.

```py
import os

def opener(path, flags):
    return os.open(path, flags, 0o777)

os.umask(0)  # Without this, the created file will have 0o777 - 0o022 (default umask) = 0o755 permissions
with open("myfile.txt", "w", opener=opener) as f:
    f.write("myline")
```

From the [documentation for `opener`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#open):

> A custom opener can be used by passing a callable as opener. The underlying file descriptor for the file object is then obtained by calling opener with (file, flags). opener must return an open file descriptor (passing os.open as opener results in functionality similar to passing None).

Comment: I like this approach for its extensibility.

Answer (score 3):

This is a robust method

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import stat
import os
path = 'outfile.txt'
with open(path, 'w') as fh:
    fh.write('blabla\n')
st = os.stat(path)
os.chmod(path, st.st_mode | stat.S_IWOTH)
```

See how:

- `stat.S_IWOTH` is used instead of the raw binary constant, which is more semantic
- we add just a single `+o` to the file, and use the `umask` by default, see also: [How do you do a simple "chmod +x" from within python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791997/how-do-you-do-a-simple-chmod-x-from-within-python)

See also: [Write file with specific permissions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624359/write-file-with-specific-permissions-in-python/15015748)

Answer (score 1):

For python 3.4+ you can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.touch) as follows

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

os.umask(0)  # get full permission spectrum

filepath = Path("/path/to/file.txt")
filepath.touch(mode=0o777)
filepath.write_text("hi")
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition to providing write permission to others: OTH, you can also add write permissions for group: GRP. Note what hierarchy you want to assign what permissions to while writing a file.

```
st = os.stat(path)
os.chmod(path, st.st_mode | stat.S_IWOTH | stat.S_IWGRP)
```