# How to automatically set permissions of future/new files in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, file-permissions

Currently, I do `sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu/<folder>`.

But, when I run a Python script which would be creating a folder named `testoutput` and write files to it, the folder is created with the `root` permissions, and hence, getting `permission denied` error while writing files to the folder.

How do I ensure that even new files in the range get the same permissions when doing `chown`? Is there a way to ensure that in Ubuntu?

The permissions of the new folder i :

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root
```

while the permission of the existing folders is:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create in python a file with permissions other users can write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745577/how-do-you-create-in-python-a-file-with-permissions-other-users-can-write)

Comment: '''https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624359/write-file-with-specific-permissions-in-python''' may this can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In nearly all operating systems, the owner of a new file is determined by the user context from which the file is created. I.e. you are most likely running the repsective python script as `root`.
If you recursively `chown` the base directory `testoutput` afterwards - as `root` of course - you shuld be fine.
If you do not want `root` to be the initial owner, consider not running the respective script as `root` in the first place, but as the desired owner.
Alternatively have a look at [ACLs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists).

Answer (score 1):

This is governed by `umask` setting which is set by default here to

```
root@brad:~# grep ^UMASK /etc/login.defs
UMASK           022
root@brad:~#
```

(though pam and other services for remote login etc pp have overrides).

With this we have:

```
root@brad:~# umask                 # four digits because of suid bit
0022
root@brad:~# mkdir tempDir1
root@brad:~# ls -ld tempDir1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 17 07:22 tempDir1
root@brad:~# umask 002
root@brad:~# umask
0002
root@brad:~# mkdir tempDir2
root@brad:~# ls -ld tempDir?
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 17 07:22 tempDir1
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 17 07:22 tempDir2
root@brad:~#
```

And you see how changing the middle digit from 022 to 002 made the group permission writeable.