# How to create undeletable folder in Python?

Tags: python

I'm writing Python code for making a new folder using the `os` module:

```py
os.makedirs(path)
```

But this folder can be deleted; I want to make a folder which cannot be deleted. Is it possible to make an undeletable text file?

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745577/how-do-you-create-in-python-a-file-with-permissions-other-users-can-write

Answer (score 4):

You can provide access rights when you create the folder

```
import os

# define the name of the directory to be created
path = "/tmp/year"

# define the access rights (readable and accessible by all users, and write access by only the owner) 
access_rights = 0o755 

try:
    os.mkdir(path, access_rights)
except OSError:
    print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % path)
else:
    print ("Successfully created the directory %s" % path)
```