# python: i have an error while trying this on my mac using IDLE on mac or terminal

Tags: python, macos

i want to see some info and get info about my os with python as in my tutorial but actually can't run this code:

```
import os
F = os.popen('dir')
```

and this :

```
F.readline()
' Volume in drive C has no label.\n'
F = os.popen('dir')               # Read by sized blocks
F.read(50)
' Volume in drive C has no label.\n Volume Serial Nu'

os.popen('dir').readlines()[0]    # Read all lines: index
' Volume in drive C has no label.\n'
os.popen('dir').read()[:50]       # Read all at once: slice
' Volume in drive C has no label.\n Volume Serial Nu'

for line in os.popen('dir'):      # File line iterator loop
...     print(line.rstrip())
```

this is the the error for the first on terminal, (on IDLE it return just an '

f = open('dir')
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "", line 1, in 
   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dir'

I know on mac it should be different but how? to get the same result
using macOS sierra.

Comment: I accidentally removed the assignment in `>>> F = os.peoen('dir')` while editing to fix the code block display of the IDLE session. Someone else unfortunately is trying to remove the IDLE session part completely (OP specifically mentions IDLE). So I have to wait for that to get rejected before fixing the editing mistake.

Comment: IDLE is not relevant to Python reporting an error when running Windows-specific code on OSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.popen` executes a program and returns a file-like object to read the program output. So, `os.popen('dir')` runs the `dir` command (which lists information about your hard drive) and gives you the result. `open` opens a file on your hard drive for reading.

Your problem is that there is no file named `dir`. You likely wanted `f = os.popen(`dir`)` MAC is different than windows and the base directory listing command is `ls`. But most unixy systems have a `dir` command that lists files in a different format, so it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are following looks like it was written for Windows. `popen` runs a command -- but there is no `dir` command on a Mac. `dir` in DOS shows you files in a directory (folder); the equivalent command on a Mac is `ls`.

Comment: Most linux systems have a `dir` that lists files and directories. Is MAC different this way?

Comment: Yes, macOS is different in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

`open` and `os.popen` *are entirely different*<sup>*</sup>.

The first one just opens a file (by default *for reading*), but the second one runs a command in your shell and gives you the ability to communicate with it (e.g. get the output).

So, given that `open` opens the file for reading when you supply only the file's name, if such a file doesn't exist, it raises an error, which is the case here.

`os.popen` executes the given command on your computer as if you typed it in the terminal.

---

<sup>* There exists another function with a similar name: `os.open`, which is, again, [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219511/whats-the-difference-between-io-open-and-os-open-on-python) from the ones mentioned earlier.</sup>