# Why the function 'os.open(file_path, flag)' returns an integer?

Tags: python-3.x, integer, return

I know I can use the function 'os.open' to deal with '.txt' files. But nevertheless I tried to open a '.jpg' file using this function as shown in the code below:

```
import os
f1 = os.open('imagem.jpg', os.O_RDONLY)
```

When I call f1 object to see what is inside it, python returns to me a integer that changes according to the number of times I have run the 'f1 = os.open('imagem.jpg', os.O_RDONLY)' code.

For example, the first time I run 'f1 = os.open('imagem.jpg', os.O_RDONLY)', f1 will assume 1, second time, 2, so on...

When I run the code below to see the methods and atributes of f1:

```
dir(f1)
```

python returns it to me:

```
['__abs__',
 '__add__',
 '__and__',
 '__bool__',
 '__ceil__',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dir__',
 '__divmod__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__float__',
 '__floor__',
 '__floordiv__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__getnewargs__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__index__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__int__',
 '__invert__',
 '__le__',
 '__lshift__',
 '__lt__',
 '__mod__',
 '__mul__',
 '__ne__',
 '__neg__',
 '__new__',
 '__or__',
 '__pos__',
 '__pow__',
 '__radd__',
 '__rand__',
 '__rdivmod__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__rfloordiv__',
 '__rlshift__',
 '__rmod__',
 '__rmul__',
 '__ror__',
 '__round__',
 '__rpow__',
 '__rrshift__',
 '__rshift__',
 '__rsub__',
 '__rtruediv__',
 '__rxor__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__sub__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__truediv__',
 '__trunc__',
 '__xor__',
 'as_integer_ratio',
 'bit_length',
 'conjugate',
 'denominator',
 'from_bytes',
 'imag',
 'numerator',
 'real',
 'to_bytes']
```

Some one can explain to me what is happening?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_open.htm

Comment: There's also this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7219535/10840671

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion helps me a lot!